# bundle a jnlp so you can add to dock on a mac?

Tags: macos, jnlp, findbugs, dock

I want to be able to drag Findbugs to the Dock on my Mac.
The problem is it's a JNLP.

Is there a distilled idiots guide to creating an Mac application bundle from a JNLP?
I saw this article on the Apple website: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html 
but it was a case of 'information overload'!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the Java Web Start section of the linked article:

> Mac OS X’s desktop integration with Java Web Start lets users can create a local application bundle from any Java Web Start application. The Shortcut Creation setting in Java Preferences controls whether the user is prompted to create an application bundle when opening a Java Web Start application. Bundled Java Web Start applications have all of the benefits of native application bundles, which are described in “Mac OS X Application Bundles.”

Try looking in Applications->Utilities->Java Preferences.  Click on the Advanced tab.  You should see the Shortcut Creation setting.  Let us know if it works for you.

Comment: I changed the setting to "Prompt User" but I'm not getting prompted to create a shortcut. Could it be that it only asks on the first run of the app? (OS X 10.6.8 with Java 1.6.0_29)